# Tomcat 8 503 Error with Apache2 mod_jk as Reverse Proxy on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I'm following this guide to setup Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu Server 16.04 using Apache2's mod_jk module as a reverse proxy:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Everything works until the last step, which is to change the HTTP and AJP Connectors in server.xml to only listen on localhost. Here's the change I made to the AJP Connector:

```
<Connector port="8009" address="127.0.0.1" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Before this change, typing https://myhostname takes me to the Tomcat administration page; after it, I get "503 Service Unavailable".

Here's the relevant portion of mod_jk.log

```
[info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (817): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 23 17:37:13.808 2017] [14484:140252643563264] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1068): (ajp13_worker) Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Thu Mar 23 17:37:13.808 2017] [14484:140252643563264] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1728): (ajp13_worker) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
```